# How to I use Textmate color themes with vim?

Tags: vim, colors, textmate, syntax-highlighting

I have a textmate color theme I really like [this](http://railscasts.com/about), 
But I am a hardcore vim user.  Is there an easy (painless) way for me to use this color scheme with vim?

Comment: and which is the textmate theme you really like? your link to the about site of railscast does not provide anything .. usefull towards your theme, does it? or do you mean the http://media.railscasts.com/resources/textmate_theme.zip ?

Comment: Yes. sorry about the bad link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of textmate color schemes for textmate in vim. Maybe you can find someone who already implemented it.

Searching in google for [textmate theme vim](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=textmate+theme+vim), the first result is:

> A GUI only color scheme based on the
>   Railscasts TextMate theme.

Is [this theme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1995) (Railcasts theme) what you're looking for?

[image]

Comment: This was the scheme I wanted.  I guess the other answer in here is that there is no easy way to convert textmate->vim themes.  Just do it manually I suppose.

Answer (score 12):

You can convert any Textmate color scheme to vim by using [coloration](https://github.com/sickill/coloration).

Comment: gem install coloration

Answer (score 0):

The default syntax highlighting in the Janus distro of VIM is what you are looking for. I explain how to download it in my [Textmate to VIM guide](http://www.jackkinsella.ie/2011/09/05/textmate-to-vim.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.